# How do we add 'transparent' to the collection of colors in mcc-color-picker-collection

Tags: angular, color-picker

If there any way to add transparent to the collection of colors in mcc-color-picker-collection?

```
<mcc-color-picker-collection
    [colors]="myColors"
    size="9"
    label="mycolors"
>
</mcc-color-picker-collection>

this.myColors = ['#FFFFFF', '#000000'];
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

Just add transparent="true" as follows.

```
<mcc-color-picker-collection
    [colors]="myColors"
    size="9"
    label="mycolors"
    transparent="true"
>
</mcc-color-picker-collection>
```